# Tomcat logrotate error: tomcat:1 bad rotation count '7 compress missingok size 5M }'

Tags: centos, logrotate, tomcat

I have a standalone Tomcat installed on CentOS 8 and I am trying to rotate the `catalina.out` file.

I have created a file named `/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat` with `vim` and added the following line:

```
/opt/tomcat9/logs/catalina.out {   copytruncate   daily   rotate 7   compress   missingok   size 5M }
```

However when I try to execute it manually I get the following error:

```
[root@dummy bin]# /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
error: tomcat:1 bad rotation count '7   compress   missingok   size 5M }'
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 3):

Each configuration directive needs to be on its own line:

```
/opt/tomcat9/logs/catalina.out {
   copytruncate
   daily
   rotate 7
   compress
   missingok
   size 5M
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had comments # at the end of each line